# Search for two elements simultaneous in Swift?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I have a struct like this:

```
struct StructName {
    var name: String?
    var contents: [Content]?

}
```

`Content` looks like this:

```
struct Content {
    var contentName: String?
}
```

Right now I am just searching by the `names` inside my array of `StructName`

```
var array = [StructName]()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String) {

    var filteredArray = array.filter { $0.name?.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil}

}
```

How would I approach this if I want to search inside the elements in `contents` simultaneous with `name` in `StructName`?

If I structured it like this:

```
let contentA = [Content(contentName: "Content_1"), Content(contentName: "Content_2")]
let contentB = [Content(contentName: "Content_1"), Content(contentName: "Content_2")]
array[0] = (StructName(name: "Name_1", contents: contentA))
array[1] = (StructName(name: "Name_2", contents: contentB))
```

And I wrote "NC" in my searchText, it should return everything, since there is an "N" in "Name_1" and "Name_2" and there is a "C" in "Content_1" and "Content_2".

Example of `filteredArray`:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredArray = array.filter{ elements in
            var result = false
            elements.contents.forEach{ content in
                if (content.contentName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ) {
                    result = true

                }
            }

            if (content.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!{
                result = true
            }

            return result
        }
  }
```

Note that this does not search simultaneously as I have described.

Comment: Simply update the expression in your filter to check `contents` as well.

Comment: You need to tell us what the `Content` type is if you want us to be more specific than rmaddy's answer.

Comment: I did that now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter and find StructNames where Content array items compares with searchBar text, when look at this code

```
struct Content {
    var contentValue: String
}

struct StructName{
    var name: String?
    var contents: [Content]?
}

var array = [ StructName(name: "test1", contents: [ Content(contentValue: "contentValue1"), Content(contentValue: "contentValue2"), Content(contentValue: "searchedText") ]) ]

let searchedText = "searchedText"

let filteredArray = array.filter{ structName in
    var result = false
    structName.contents?.forEach{ content in
        if (content.contentValue.lowercased().contains(searchedText.lowercased()) ) {
            result = true
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I wanted to search for the elements simultaneous.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of the word *simultaneous* is not clear enough to describe what sort of search result you expect.

I assume,

if (and only if) `name` *matches* `searchText` or any `contentName` in `contents` *matches* `searchText`, the `StructName` instance appears in the `filteredArray`.

(*matches* is defined similar as your `name` in your post.)

Then you can write something like this:

```
var filteredArray = array.filter {
    $0.name?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
||  $0.contents?.contains {content in content.contentName?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil} == true
}
```

If this is not what you want, you may need to specify your search condition more precisely.

---

(By the way, `name` or `contents` needs to be Optional?)

---

#### (For your updated example)

Seems you want character based searching with every character needs to hit.

Using a little bit modified example:

```
var array = [StructName]()
let contentA = [Content(contentName: "Content_1"), Content(contentName: "Content_2")]
let contentB = [Content(contentName: "Content_3"), Content(contentName: "Content_4")]
array.append(StructName(name: "Name_1", contents: contentA))
array.append(StructName(name: "Name_2", contents: contentB))
```

with some debugging help:

```
extension StructName: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(name ?? ""):\(contents?.map{$0.contentName ?? ""}.joined(separator: ";") ?? "")"
    }
}
print(array) //->[Name_1:Content_1;Content_2, Name_2:Content_3;Content_4]
```

You can write something like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String) {
    let filteredArray = array.filter {element in
        !searchText.lowercased().contains {searchChar in
            !(element.name ?? "").lowercased().contains(searchChar)
                && !(element.contents ?? []).contains {content in (content.contentName ?? "").lowercased().contains(searchChar)}
        }
    }
    print(filteredArray)
}
```

Output example:

```
searchBar(UISearchBar(), textDidChange: "NC") //->[Name_1:Content_1;Content_2, Name_2:Content_3;Content_4]
searchBar(UISearchBar(), textDidChange: "1")  //->[Name_1:Content_1;Content_2]
searchBar(UISearchBar(), textDidChange: "2")  //->[Name_1:Content_1;Content_2, Name_2:Content_3;Content_4]
searchBar(UISearchBar(), textDidChange: "12") //->[Name_1:Content_1;Content_2]
```

Though, I'm not sure if this is what you expect, as your description is not clear enough yet.

Comment: @Testtester, your updated description is more confusing than clear. Create an example of `array` (written in Swift, please), and show some examples of `searchText` and expected results for each `searchText`.